# AWS - sudo: unable to resolve host ip-x-x-x-x: Resource temporarily unavailable and i can't change /etc/hosts cause it's readonly

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, sudo

Every time i type "sudo" in my ec2 AWS i get the following error:

`sudo: unable to resolve host ip-x-x-x-x: Resource temporarily unavailable`

I searched online and found that I have to add the following line to the /etc/hosts file

`127.0.0.1 ip-x-x-x-x`

but my /etc/hosts is a read only file and therefore I cannot write to it.
DNS resolutions and DNS hostnames are both set to enable in my VPC configuration.

How can i make sudo work normally again?

Comment: If your root file system is EBS, you can stop this instance, detach the volume and attach it to a new instance, where you'll be able to sudo edit the host file. Once you are done, attach it back to this instance and restart.